# Chrome Extension open popup by command

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use a shortcut `Ctrl + B` to open `popup.html` of my extension, so I don't need to move the mouse and click.

I tried the `commands` config from Google document but it seems doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this? Below is my configuration (Note that I'm using `manifest_version: 3`)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
"commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+B",
        "mac": "Ctrl+B"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```js
// Currently empty
```

Comment: https://crbug.com/1190476

Comment: @wOxxOm I see, thank you. So currently the only option is using manifest v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this works for you, but if position of popup.html is not an issue for you this shall work if added to your background.js script. (executed on local host in manifest version 3)

manifest.json

```
 "commands": {
 "my_shortcut": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Ctrl+B",
    "mac": "Command+B"
  },
  "description": "Opens popup.html",
  "global": true
},
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {

if (command === 'my_shortcut')
    chrome.system.display.getInfo({ singleUnified: true }, (info) => {
    
      const wDimension = info[0].workArea;
      const { top, left, height, width } = wDimension;
      console.log(top);
      const w = 440;
      const h = 220;
      const l = width / 2 - w / 2 + left;
      const t = height / 2 - h / 2 + top;
      const newWindow = () => {
        console.log('in new window function');
      };
      chrome.windows.create(
        {
          url: 'popup.html',
          type: 'popup',
          width: w,
          height: h,
          left: Math.round(l),
          top: Math.round(t),
        },
        newWindow
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm think it's the best approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mac, you will need to use `MacCtrl` instead of `Ctrl`

```
"commands": {
"_execute_action": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Ctrl+B",
    "mac": "MacCtrl+B"
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Because this doesn't answer the original issue, this is better suited to the comment section than a full answer.